# How to generate a summary statistics table with all relevant decimal places to appear in the resulting table in R?

Tags: r, statistics, scientific-notation, leading-zero, significant-digits

I have an exceptionally large dataset (50+ Sites, 100+ Solutes) and I would like to quickly generate a summary table of descriptive statistics for the data and be able export it as a .csv file.

Sample code (a very small subset of my data):

```
Site <- c( "SC2", "SC2" , "SC2", "SC3" , "SC3" ,"SC3", "SC4", "SC4" ,"SC4","SC4","SC4")
Aluminum <- as.numeric(c(0.0565,  0.0668 ,0.0785,0.0292,0.0576,0.075,0.029,0.088,0.076,0.007,0.107))
Antimony <- as.numeric(c(0.0000578,  0.0000698, 0.0000215,0.000025,0.0000389,0.0000785,0.0000954,0.00005447,0.00007843,0.000025,0.0000124))

stats_data <- data.frame(Site, Aluminum, Antimony, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

stats_data_gather =stats_data %>% gather(Solute, value, -Site)

table_test = stats_data_gather %>% 
  group_by(Site, Solute) %>%
  get_summary_stats(value, show = c("mean", "sd", "min", "q1", "median", "q3", "max"))
```

This results in a dataframe that calculates the required statistics BUT, results are truncated to only three decimal places (i.e. what should be something like 0.00000057 appears as 0.000).

I have tried variations of using:

```
options(digits = XX), 
format(DF, format = "e", digits = 2),
format.data.frame(table_test, digits = 8)
```

I have tried these and other sample code found online but none will reproduce a summary dataframe that includes all necessary zeros for small number results (i.e. 0.00000057, not 0.000). I would even be fine with scientific notation but I haven't been successful in finding an example that will work.

This is my first post. I hope I have provided enough detail for help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because in `get_summary_stats`, it is hardcoded to return 3 digits:

```
get_summary_stats
function (data, ..., type = c("full", "common", "robust", "five_number", 
    "mean_sd", "mean_se", "mean_ci", "median_iqr", "median_mad", 
    "quantile", "mean", "median", "min", "max"), show = NULL, 
    probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25)) 
{
  ..... 
        dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 3)
    if (!is.null(show)) {
        show <- unique(c("variable", "n", show))
        results <- results %>% select(!!!syms(show))
    }
    results
}
```

You can either hack to code above, or for what you do, use a `summarise_all` function like below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

stats_data_gather %>%  group_by(Site, Solute) %>% summarise_all(list(~mean(.),~sd(.),
~list(c(summary(.))))) %>% unnest_wider(list)

# A tibble: 6 x 10
# Groups:   Site [3]
  Site  Solute    mean      sd    Min. `1st Qu.`  Median    Mean `3rd Qu.`
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 SC2   Alumi… 6.73e-2 1.10e-2 5.65e-2 0.0616    6.68e-2 6.73e-2 0.0726   
2 SC2   Antim… 4.97e-5 2.51e-5 2.15e-5 0.0000396 5.78e-5 4.97e-5 0.0000638
3 SC3   Alumi… 5.39e-2 2.31e-2 2.92e-2 0.0434    5.76e-2 5.39e-2 0.0663   
4 SC3   Antim… 4.75e-5 2.78e-5 2.50e-5 0.0000320 3.89e-5 4.75e-5 0.0000587
5 SC4   Alumi… 6.14e-2 4.19e-2 7.00e-3 0.029     7.60e-2 6.14e-2 0.088    
6 SC4   Antim… 5.31e-5 3.49e-5 1.24e-5 0.000025  5.45e-5 5.31e-5 0.0000784
# … with 1 more variable: Max. <dbl>
```

The column names might be a bit bad, but you can easily rename them to q1 and q3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `summary` function for the stats you are looking for:

```r
sum.table <- summary(stats_data_gather)
```

Then you can take the summarized variables from 3rd column using:

```r
as.numeric(sub('.*:', '', sum.table[,3]))
```